# Can not install ubuntu on my Overpowered laptop

Tags: system-installation

I did install ubuntu on 2 of my devices. Then I bought an Overpowered laptop on Walmart. But it didn't work. It's always frozen after I fill my password and hit log in.

[image: Error showing before the ubuntu loading showed]

When I try to install ubuntu, I have to turn off the ACPI too. I wonder if it has something to do with the problem.